# Is there a way to start mitmproxy v.7.0.2 programmatically in the background?

Tags: mitmproxy

### Is there a way to start mitmproxy v.7.0.2 programmatically in the background?
ProxyConfig and ProxyServer have been removed since version 7.0.0, and the code below isn't working.

```
from mitmproxy.options import Options
from mitmproxy.proxy.config import ProxyConfig
from mitmproxy.proxy.server import ProxyServer
from mitmproxy.tools.dump import DumpMaster

import threading
import asyncio
import time

class Addon(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 1

    def request(self, flow):
        flow.request.headers["count"] = str(self.num)

    def response(self, flow):
        self.num = self.num + 1
        flow.response.headers["count"] = str(self.num)
        print(self.num)


# see source mitmproxy/master.py for details
def loop_in_thread(loop, m):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)  # This is the key.
    m.run_loop(loop.run_forever)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = Options(listen_host='0.0.0.0', listen_port=8080, http2=True)
    m = DumpMaster(options, with_termlog=False, with_dumper=False)
    config = ProxyConfig(options)
    m.server = ProxyServer(config)
    m.addons.add(Addon())

    # run mitmproxy in backgroud, especially integrated with other server
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    t = threading.Thread( target=loop_in_thread, args=(loop,m) )
    t.start()

    # Other servers, such as a web server, might be started then.
    time.sleep(20)
    print('going to shutdown mitmproxy')
    m.shutdown()
```

[from BigSully's gist](https://gist.github.com/BigSully/3da478792ee331cb2e5ece748393f8c4)

Answer (score 4):

You can put your `Addon` class into `your_script.py` and then run `mitmdump -s your_script.py`. mitmdump comes without the console interface and can run in the background.

We (mitmproxy devs) officially don't support manual instantiation from Python anymore because that creates a massive amount of support burden for us. If you have some Python experience you can probably find your way around.

##### What if my addon has additional dependencies?

**Approach 1:** `pip install mitmproxy` is still perfectly supported and gets you the same functionality as the standalone binaries. Bonus tip: You can run `venv/bin/mitmproxy` or `venv/Scripts/mitmproxy.exe` to invoke mitmproxy in your virtualenv without having your virtualenv activated.

**Approach 2:** You can install mitmproxy with `pipx` and then run `pipx inject mitmproxy <your dependency name>`. See https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-installation/#installation-from-the-python-package-index-pypi for details.

##### How can I debug mitmproxy itself?

If you are debugging from the command line (be it print statements or pdb), the easiest approach is to run `mitmdump` instead of `mitmproxy`, which provides the same functionality minus the console interface. Alternatively, you can use PyCharm's remote debug functionality, which also works while the console interface is active (https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/main/examples/contrib/remote-debug.py).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If your own script needs other libraries that you would normally install in a virtual environment, how is the recommended way to do this with mitmproxy now? Also, is there still some way to write the code in a GUI like pycharm and have debugger access?

Comment: I've expanded my answer, see above. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    from mitmproxy.addons.proxyserver import Proxyserver
    from mitmproxy.options import Options
    from mitmproxy.tools.dump import DumpMaster
    options = Options(listen_host='127.0.0.1', listen_port=8080, http2=True)
    m = DumpMaster(options, with_termlog=True, with_dumper=False)
    m.server = Proxyserver()
    m.addons.add(
            // addons here
    )
    m.run()
```

Hi, I think that should do it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This example below should work fine with mitmproxy v7

```py
from mitmproxy.tools import main
from mitmproxy.tools.dump import DumpMaster

options = main.options.Options(listen_host='0.0.0.0', listen_port=8080)
m = DumpMaster(options=options)
# the rest is same in the previous versions
```